# Error en mi código de Java - Scanner y Switch/Case

Tags: java, sql

soy un principiante en esto de java y he estado creando algunos códigos para agarrar un poco más de velocidad. He creado una especie de sistema con la util Scanner y usando las funciones switch/case para que el usuario al poner un número del 1 al 7 te diga el día de la semana que corresponde ese número (ejemplo el usuario pone 1 y el sistema dice Lunes).

https://pastebin.com/kCEfWdp7  Este es el código que creé.

El compilador me marca este error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxfvD.jpg

Espero una respuesta y muchas gracias :D

Comment: Hola y bienvenido. El código sobre el que quieras preguntar en SO se incluye dentro de la pregunta. Si Pastebin cambia algún día o se muere, tu pregunta dejará de ser útil para las personas que la vean en el futuro y tengan el mismo problema. Así mismo, los errores se copian y pegan como texto (a menos que sean problemas de interfaz gráfica que se exlpiquen mejor vistos). Saludos y buena suerte!

Answer (score 1):

¡Hola Víctor!
Lo primero bienvenido al mundo de la programación.

Si te fijas bien, el compilador te indica que no encuentra un símbolo (el cual está marcado con una flechita). Este símbolo te especifica que es el método NextInt(), y es que resulta que debería ir en minúsculas la primera 'n'.

En la línea 10, deberías ponerlo en minúsculas, tal que así:

```
    num_dia = test.nextInt();
```

Tal y como te indica @Alfabravo, deberías poner el código directamente en stackoverflow y no en Paste.bin, pues si se elimina el paste, o bien se cierra la página, esta respuesta no ayudará a nadie más.

Es muy importante aprender a leer los errores y entenderlos, por lo que te recomiendo que siempre que te de un error revises muy bien lo que te está diciendo, e intentes entender por qué. Es posible que en este caso no supieras que el nombre de los métodos, variables, objetos, etc. en Java es "case sensitive", es decir, las mayúsculas importan.

P.D: Por otro lado, en cada caso compruebas si el día es X, y vuelves a asignarle valor X a la misma variable en:

```
 case 1: num_dia = 1;
```

Por lo que deberías simplemente dejar `case 1:` a secas.

Un saludo